# GNU Utils in Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, emulators

Can we install GNU utils on Android emulator?

Depending on emulator's platform (x86, x86_64, arm64, armabi, etc), can one install corresponding GNU utils build? I mostly interested in vim on emulator.

Comment: By GNU Utils, did you mean [GNU core utilities](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html)? I couldn't find any reference to `gnu-utils`.

Comment: yes, I should have said coreutils.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can install GNU utils *directly* on Android, because Android is not GNU/Linux.

From [Coreutils - GNU core utilities](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html),

> ## Introduction to Coreutils
>
> The GNU Core Utilities are the basic file, shell and text manipulation utilities of the **GNU operating system**.
> These are the core utilities which are expected to exist on every operating system.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

But [Android is not GNU/Linux](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/android-and-users-freedom.html)

> Android is very different from the [GNU/Linux operating system](https://www.gnu.org/gnu/the-gnu-project.html) because it contains very little of GNU. Indeed, just about the only component in common between Android and GNU/Linux is Linux, the kernel. People who erroneously think “Linux” refers to the entire GNU/Linux combination get tied in knots by these facts, and make paradoxical statements such as “Android contains Linux, but it isn't Linux.”([*](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/android-and-users-freedom.html#linuxnote)) Absent this confusion, the situation is simple: **Android contains Linux, but not GNU; thus, Android and GNU/Linux are mostly different, because all they have in common is Linux**.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

...*however*, [alireza7991 from XDA forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2613243) was trying to port them to Android.

> **Requirements**: an ARM v7 processor with built-in NEON SIMD (scorpion, krait, exynose 4, exynose 5,...)
>
> **Installation**
>
> - Be sure you meet the requirements!
> - Get the zip file ([CoreUtils on Android v1](http://d-h.st/ee6))
> - Flash it via recovery mod
> - Reboot and enjoy
>
> **Usage**
>
> To avoid issues of having busybox and coreutils at same time, all utils are named in form : `cu.${UTIL_NAME}`. For example:
>
> ```
> cu.echo "hello world!"
> cu.chmod 644 /system/build.prop
> ```
>
> **Bugs**: a few utils such as `ls` and `uname` are broken down till I fix them and add the correct one to repository. Some utils are missed. (currently we have 103 applets working)

Further reading: [BusyBox Replacement on the Horizon? Meet GNU CoreUtils on Android](http://www.xda-developers.com/busybox-replacement-on-the-horizon-meet-gnu-coreutils-on-android/)

---

PS. If you want to use Vim on Android, why don't you use [Vim Touch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.momodalo.app.vimtouch) or [Terminal IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside), or search "vim" on Play Store instead?

Comment: I do some feeble Android development as hobby, thus was looking for vim in emulator. not an app. it shall work in `adb shell`